# How to build a table with JSON data that came from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

My attempt to dynamically build an HTML table was futile.
Code works, but it doesn't output exactly what I need.
There are only 2 properties within my JSON output: `location` and `completed_on`
Instead of getting this:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+
|     Location      |    Completed on     |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| 10 Duskwood Dr.   | 2015-07-06 14:10:42 |
| 2 Booty Bay Blvd. | 2015-07-09 13:44:38 |
+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Code shows this(no thead visible):

```
[
{
"
l
o
c
a
...
]
... prints the whole JSON character by character inside many <td> tags...
```

This is an example of a typical JSON data I have to work with:

```
[{"location":"10 Duskwood Dr.","completed_on":"2015-07-06 14:10:42"},
{"location":"2 Booty Bay Blvd.","completed_on":"2015-07-09 13:44:38"}]
```

This is the table markup I have hard coded into HTML and update with JSON:

```
<table id="completed_locations" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Completed on</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        // JSON data goes here
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I use this code to build `<tr>` and `<td>`:

```
// this is called within success of ajax to build table
var oldTable = document.getElementById('completed_locations'),
    newTable = oldTable.cloneNode();
for(var i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j = 0; j < output[i].length; j++){
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(output[i][j]));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    newTable.appendChild(tr);
}
oldTable.parentNode.replaceChild(newTable, oldTable);
```

Comment: Cerbrus has already pointed out your first problem (you have a JSON string, you need to parse it to get the actual JavaScript array). The next thing you'll need to fix is the creation of the `<td>` elements, which looks wrong if you have an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your `output` variable is still in it's JSON string format.
This would cause the `for` loops to iterate over every single letter in the string, instead of over every entry in the array.

Try adding:

```
output = JSON.parse(output);
```

before your `for` loops.

The reason this doesn't throw any errors, is because the outer loop iterates over the full length of the JSON string, then in the inner loop, `output[i].length` always is `1`, since it's a 1-character string. The inner loop will always access `output[i][0]`, and then terminate that loop.

Now, to fix the actual creation of the table:

```js
var output = '[{"location":"10 Duskwood Dr.","completed_on":"2015-07-06 14:10:42"},{"location":"2 Booty Bay Blvd.","completed_on":"2015-07-09 13:44:38"}]',
    oldTable = document.getElementById('completed_locations'),
    newTable = oldTable.cloneNode();

output = JSON.parse(output);

for(var i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    // No need to loop here with only 2 properties
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(output[i].location));
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(output[i].completed_on));
    tr.appendChild(td);

    newTable.appendChild(tr);
}
oldTable.parentNode.replaceChild(newTable, oldTable);
```

```html
<table id="completed_locations" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Completed on</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        // JSON data goes here
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have more columns, you could loop over them, instead:

```
var columns = ['location', 'completed_on'];
for(var i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr'),
        td;

    for(var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++){
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(output[i][columns[j]]));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    newTable.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: That made my `alert(output)` show `[object Object],[object Object]`, and now nothing shows up in the table.

Comment: Good, that means `output` is an actual object now, just a JSON string. Now we just have to iterate over it.

Comment: At last, I truly see. Thanks.